# StatusBarColor doesn't change

Tags: android, themes, statusbar

I have imported this library https://github.com/neokree/MaterialNavigationDrawer
for my `NavigationDrawer`. I used a suggested theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="MaterialNavigationDrawerTheme.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#8bc34a</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#558b2f</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="singleAccount">true</item>
</style>
```

When I create a new `ActionBarActivity` the statusBar is white and I can't understand why. The `colorPrimaryDark` is ignored.
How can I make the status bar of the default color?

Comment: Are you running on Android Lollipop or newer? I don't think it's possible to change the status bar background color on older platform versions.

Comment: I am running on Lollipod. The problem is the white color of status bar. I didn't set this color white.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this code in the `oncreate` function of your activity

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(Color.parseColor("#0288d1"));
}
```

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base" />
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="MaterialNavigationDrawerTheme.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">#8bc34a</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#558b2f</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="singleAccount">true</item>
   </style>
</style>